# How should I go about casting an __n128 to an __n64x2?

Tags: c++, arm, simd, neon

I have an __n128 that I want to use as input for the vtbl2_u8 intrinsic, and it doesn't like it.  vreinterpret doesn't seem to have to have a variant that works on __n128 so far as I can tell, and these things seem to be finicky about reinterpret_cast.  I'm much more used to SSE2 so... any guidance for an ARM NEON noob?

Edit:

More specifically, could I get an idea as to why:

```
        static __forceinline __n128 byteshuffle(
            _In_ const __n128& x,
            _In_ const __n128& mask)
        {
            uint8x8x2_t in =
            {
                x.n128_u64[0],
                x.n128_u64[1]
            };
            __n128 out;

            out.n128_u64[0] = vtbl2_u8(in, mask.n128_u64[0]);
            out.n128_u64[1] = vtbl2_u8(in, mask.n128_u64[1]);
            return out;
        }
```

doesn't compile?  Error is 'no suitable constructor exists to convert "const unsigned long long" to "__n64"' on both vtbl lines.

Answer (score 1):

The `vreinterpret_X_Y` macro is used for taking an existing register and 'casting' the type to some other form to pass along to another intrinsic. For example, this code loads up two 16-bit signed shorts in a single load as a 32-bit unsigned int, but then I have to use `vreinterpret_s16_u32` because I don't actually want to treat the data as a `uint32x2_t` and instead I want it to be `int16x4_t` which is exactly the same size in bytes (i.e. they both map to `__n64` values).

```
// ptr is an input pointer to two uint16_t values
uint32x2_t vInt16 = vld1_dup_u32( reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(ptr) );
int32x4_t vInt = vmovl_s16( vreinterpret_s16_u32(vInt16) );
```

**Note:** `vreinterpret_X_Y`  does exactly what `_mm_castX_Y` does for SSE. I.e., nothing. It doesn't emit any code, it just makes the compiler happier about the type changes. It's worth noting that Visual Studio's ARM C++ compiler doesn't really do much type checking in this regard since everything is really treated as a `__n64` or `__n128` type anyhow. As such, `vreinterpret_X_Y` is mostly a matter of code portability.

The table look-up intrinsics, however, are a bit of a special case. You have to load up the `uint8x8x2_t` type and can't just cast an existing variable to it.

Note: This also applies to `vtbxl`, `vtrn`, `vzip`, `vuzp`, `vld2+`, and `vst2+` intrinsics.

For example, in [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx) I implemented the ARM-NEON version of the general `XMVectorSwizzle` using two `vtbl2_u8` lookups:

```
// DirectXMathVector.inl
inline XMVECTOR XM_CALLCONV XMVectorSwizzle(FXMVECTOR V,
    uint32_t E0, uint32_t E1, uint32_t E2, uint32_t E3)
{
    assert( (E0 < 4) && (E1 < 4) && (E2 < 4) && (E3 < 4) );

    static const uint32_t ControlElement[ 4 ] =
    {
        0x03020100, // XM_SWIZZLE_X
        0x07060504, // XM_SWIZZLE_Y
        0x0B0A0908, // XM_SWIZZLE_Z
        0x0F0E0D0C, // XM_SWIZZLE_W
    };

    int8x8x2_t tbl;
    tbl.val[0] = vget_low_f32(V);
    tbl.val[1] = vget_high_f32(V);

    uint32x2_t idx = vcreate_u32( ((uint64_t)ControlElement[E0])
                     | (((uint64_t)ControlElement[E1]) << 32) );
    const uint8x8_t rL = vtbl2_u8( tbl, idx );

    idx = vcreate_u32( ((uint64_t)ControlElement[E2])
          | (((uint64_t)ControlElement[E3]) << 32) );
    const uint8x8_t rH = vtbl2_u8( tbl, idx );

    return vcombine_f32( rL, rH );
}
```

Similarly, I used `vtbl4_u8` for `XMVectorPermute`

Note that while `vtbl` is pretty powerful, it's a bit complicated to use. For 'common' swizzle patterns, I implemented a template form of both `XMVectorSwizzle` and `XMVectorPermute` so I could specialize cases that didn't require the full table lookup:

```
// General swizzle template
template<uint32_t SwizzleX, uint32_t SwizzleY, uint32_t SwizzleZ, uint32_t SwizzleW>
inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle(FXMVECTOR V)
{
    static_assert(SwizzleX <= 3, "SwizzleX template parameter out of range");
    static_assert(SwizzleY <= 3, "SwizzleY template parameter out of range");
    static_assert(SwizzleZ <= 3, "SwizzleZ template parameter out of range");
    static_assert(SwizzleW <= 3, "SwizzleW template parameter out of range");

    return XMVectorSwizzle( V, SwizzleX, SwizzleY, SwizzleZ, SwizzleW );
}

// Specialized swizzles
template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<0,1,2,3>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return V; }

template<> inline XMVECTORXMVectorSwizzle<0,0,0,0>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return vdupq_lane_f32( vget_low_f32(V), 0); }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<1,1,1,1>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return vdupq_lane_f32( vget_low_f32(V), 1); }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<2,2,2,2>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return vdupq_lane_f32( vget_high_f32(V), 0); }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<3,3,3,3>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return vdupq_lane_f32( vget_high_f32(V), 1); }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<1,0,3,2>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return vrev64q_f32(V); }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<0,1,0,1>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { float32x2_t vt = vget_low_f32(V); return vcombine_f32( vt, vt ); }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<2,3,2,3>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { float32x2_t vt = vget_high_f32(V); return vcombine_f32( vt, vt ); }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<1,0,1,0>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { float32x2_t vt = vrev64_f32( vget_low_f32(V) ); return vcombine_f32( vt, vt ); }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<3,2,3,2>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { float32x2_t vt = vrev64_f32( vget_high_f32(V) ); return vcombine_f32( vt, vt ); }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<0,1,3,2>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return vcombine_f32( vget_low_f32(V), vrev64_f32( vget_high_f32(V) ) ); }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<1,0,2,3>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return vcombine_f32( vrev64_f32( vget_low_f32(V) ), vget_high_f32(V) ); }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<2,3,1,0>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return vcombine_f32( vget_high_f32(V), vrev64_f32( vget_low_f32(V) ) ); }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<3,2,0,1>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return vcombine_f32( vrev64_f32( vget_high_f32(V) ), vget_low_f32(V) ); }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<3,2,1,0>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return vcombine_f32( vrev64_f32( vget_high_f32(V) ), vrev64_f32( vget_low_f32(V) ) ); }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<0,0,2,2>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return vtrnq_f32(V,V).val[0]; }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<1,1,3,3>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return vtrnq_f32(V,V).val[1]; }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<0,0,1,1>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return vzipq_f32(V,V).val[0]; }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<2,2,3,3>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return vzipq_f32(V,V).val[1]; }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<0,2,0,2>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return vuzpq_f32(V,V).val[0]; }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<1,3,1,3>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return vuzpq_f32(V,V).val[1]; }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<1,2,3,0>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return vextq_f32(V, V, 1); }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<2,3,0,1>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return vextq_f32(V, V, 2); }

template<> inline XMVECTOR XMVectorSwizzle<3,0,1,2>(FXMVECTOR V)
    { return vextq_f32(V, V, 3); }
```

Comment: Informative answer, but I guess I still don't understand well enough; I've edited my question--could you have another look?

Comment: The key thing to note is that ``vtbl2_u8`` doesn't operate on ``__n128``, it operates on two ``__n64`` registers which are not the same type. There are no full 128-bit versions of the ARM-NEON ``vtbl`` intrinsic. This is unlike say ``vadd_u8`` (the ``__n64`` version) and ``vaddq_u8`` (the ``__n128`` version). i.e. there is no ``vtblXq_Y`` instrinsic. BTW, I found [this GCC listing](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html) really helpful when writing my ARM-NEON implementations.

Comment: If you are using VS 2012, VS 2013, or VS 2015 then take a look at DirectXMath which is in the Windows 8.x SDK that comes with the compiler. It's an all inline header implementation so you can see the C, SSE, and ARM-NEON versions of the functions all side-by-side.